# AWS MSK , Kafka producer throughput relation with number of partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, aws-msk

Partitions define the unit of parallelism in kafka , but increasing partitions may result in decreased producer throughput as due to replication,cluster bandwidth will decrease.

but in experiments it was observed ,
**With 3 brokers:** When we take 2 partitions on each broker then performance reduces as compared to 1 partition on each broker.

**With 9 brokers:** When we take 3 partitions on each broker then performance increases as compared to 1 partition on each broker.
**Considering the scenerio of 3 brokers the performance should have degraded but it increased.**

*What can be the reason for such behaviour ??*

**Experiment details:**
kafka-producer-perf-test was used to do benchmarking

**Parameters passed to tool:** --num-records 12000000 --throughput -1 acks=1 linger.ms=100 buffer.memory=5242880 compression.type=none request.timeout.ms=30000 --record-size 1000

Results of test in attached [image]image

Comment: Is your topic replication factor larger than 1? What is the context of your affirmation? "Partitions define the unit of parallelism in kafka, but increasing partitions may result in decreased producer throughput as due to replication, cluster bandwidth will decrease."

Comment: @GerardGarcia The replication factor is 3. 
My doubt is with 3 brokers, throughput decreases with 6 partitions ie. 2 partition/broker.
But with 9 brokers, throughput increases till 27 partitions ie. 3 partitions/broker.
Why the throughput increases till 3 partitions/ broker with 9 brokers but not with 3 brokers?

Comment: Have you identified what could be the bottleneck by looking at the broker metrics? For example, more partitions mean more concurrent writes to disk, which increases random writes and may create contention between partitions.

Comment: @GerardGarcia But this behaviour should be consistent for both 9 brokers and 3 brokers . right?
Can you help me with which metrics in cloudwatch can help me check the contention issue?

Comment: It's unclear what heap sizes you've allowed for Kafka or what volume types, but heap + RAM usage, network and disk I/O (+swap, if allowed), and CPU load are all metrics to look at. As mentioned, if you have more partitions than brokers, then there is more disk contention (less you mount **multiple disk volumes per broker**, which you've not mentioned), causing less throughput